How to properly create secondary y-axis with percentage scale and multiple lines in R?
This question might be duplicare. Sorry for that. However, none of the providing solutions work in my case.
On the primary axis I need to put the sum of the broj for each month as a bar.
On the secondary axis I need to put the percentag of each obdukcija for each month as a line. However, it is difficult to create a proper limit for the secondary y-axis.
data_df <- structure(
  list(
    year_month = c(
      "2017-01",
      "2017-01",
      "2017-01",
      "2017-01",
      "2017-02",
      "2017-02",
      "2017-02",
      "2017-02",
      "2017-03",
      "2017-03",
      "2017-03",
      "2017-03",
      "2017-04",
      "2017-04",
      "2017-04",
      "2017-04",
      "2017-05",
      "2017-05",
      "2017-05",
      "2017-05",
      "2017-06",
      "2017-06",
      "2017-06",
      "2017-06",
      "2017-07",
      "2017-07",
      "2017-07",
      "2017-07",
      "2017-08",
      "2017-08",
      "2017-08",
      "2017-08",
      "2017-09",
      "2017-09",
      "2017-09",
      "2017-09",
      "2017-10",
      "2017-10",
      "2017-10",
      "2017-10",
      "2017-11",
      "2017-11",
      "2017-11",
      "2017-11",
      "2017-12",
      "2017-12",
      "2017-12",
      "2017-12",
      "2018-01",
      "2018-01",
      "2018-01",
      "2018-01",
      "2018-02",
      "2018-02",
      "2018-02",
      "2018-02",
      "2018-03",
      "2018-03",
      "2018-03",
      "2018-03",
      "2018-04",
      "2018-04",
      "2018-04",
      "2018-04",
      "2018-05",
      "2018-05",
      "2018-05",
      "2018-05",
      "2018-06",
      "2018-06",
      "2018-06",
      "2018-06",
      "2018-07",
      "2018-07",
      "2018-07",
      "2018-07",
      "2018-08",
      "2018-08",
      "2018-08",
      "2018-08",
      "2018-09",
      "2018-09",
      "2018-09",
      "2018-09",
      "2018-10",
      "2018-10",
      "2018-10",
      "2018-10",
      "2018-11",
      "2018-11",
      "2018-11",
      "2018-11",
      "2018-12",
      "2018-12",
      "2018-12",
      "2018-12",
      "2019-01",
      "2019-01",
      "2019-01",
      "2019-01",
      "2019-02",
      "2019-02",
      "2019-02",
      "2019-02",
      "2019-03",
      "2019-03",
      "2019-03",
      "2019-03",
      "2019-04",
      "2019-04",
      "2019-04",
      "2019-04",
      "2019-05",
      "2019-05",
      "2019-05",
      "2019-05",
      "2019-06",
      "2019-06",
      "2019-06",
      "2019-06",
      "2019-07",
      "2019-07",
      "2019-07",
      "2019-07",
      "2019-08",
      "2019-08",
      "2019-08",
      "2019-08",
      "2019-09",
      "2019-09",
      "2019-09",
      "2019-09",
      "2019-10",
      "2019-10",
      "2019-10",
      "2019-10",
      "2019-11",
      "2019-11",
      "2019-11",
      "2019-11",
      "2019-12",
      "2019-12",
      "2019-12",
      "2019-12"
    ),
    obdukcija = c(
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne",
      "Da - klini�\u008dka",
      "Da - leš je oslobo�\u0091en obdukcije",
      "Da - sudsko-medicinska",
      "Ne"
    ),
    broj = c(
      78L,
      32L,
      20L,
      96L,
      46L,
      26L,
      17L,
      57L,
      44L,
      22L,
      20L,
      78L,
      42L,
      24L,
      27L,
      76L,
      44L,
      25L,
      21L,
      97L,
      37L,
      20L,
      13L,
      69L,
      44L,
      21L,
      19L,
      66L,
      43L,
      27L,
      27L,
      91L,
      39L,
      20L,
      19L,
      67L,
      48L,
      30L,
      13L,
      85L,
      43L,
      28L,
      16L,
      80L,
      40L,
      30L,
      23L,
      98L,
      50L,
      12L,
      31L,
      101L,
      32L,
      11L,
      28L,
      74L,
      41L,
      7L,
      36L,
      101L,
      40L,
      15L,
      36L,
      95L,
      45L,
      9L,
      29L,
      76L,
      33L,
      9L,
      26L,
      79L,
      47L,
      10L,
      34L,
      73L,
      47L,
      13L,
      29L,
      59L,
      38L,
      4L,
      30L,
      67L,
      37L,
      6L,
      32L,
      64L,
      37L,
      10L,
      25L,
      77L,
      33L,
      21L,
      13L,
      90L,
      55L,
      8L,
      29L,
      99L,
      34L,
      9L,
      36L,
      90L,
      49L,
      3L,
      26L,
      104L,
      34L,
      10L,
      26L,
      74L,
      27L,
      9L,
      34L,
      113L,
      36L,
      6L,
      20L,
      96L,
      27L,
      8L,
      19L,
      109L,
      33L,
      17L,
      28L,
      132L,
      39L,
      14L,
      28L,
      140L,
      35L,
      23L,
      26L,
      178L,
      35L,
      10L,
      19L,
      180L,
      56L,
      21L,
      16L,
      158L
    ),
    percent = c(
      0.345132743362832,
      0.141592920353982,
      0.0884955752212389,
      0.424778761061947,
      0.315068493150685,
      0.178082191780822,
      0.116438356164384,
      0.39041095890411,
      0.268292682926829,
      0.134146341463415,
      0.121951219512195,
      0.475609756097561,
      0.248520710059172,
      0.142011834319527,
      0.159763313609467,
      0.449704142011834,
      0.235294117647059,
      0.133689839572193,
      0.112299465240642,
      0.518716577540107,
      0.266187050359712,
      0.143884892086331,
      0.0935251798561151,
      0.496402877697842,
      0.293333333333333,
      0.14,
      0.126666666666667,
      0.44,
      0.228723404255319,
      0.143617021276596,
      0.143617021276596,
      0.484042553191489,
      0.268965517241379,
      0.137931034482759,
      0.131034482758621,
      0.462068965517241,
      0.272727272727273,
      0.170454545454545,
      0.0738636363636364,
      0.482954545454545,
      0.25748502994012,
      0.167664670658683,
      0.0958083832335329,
      0.479041916167665,
      0.209424083769634,
      0.157068062827225,
      0.120418848167539,
      0.513089005235602,
      0.257731958762887,
      0.0618556701030928,
      0.15979381443299,
      0.520618556701031,
      0.220689655172414,
      0.0758620689655172,
      0.193103448275862,
      0.510344827586207,
      0.221621621621622,
      0.0378378378378378,
      0.194594594594595,
      0.545945945945946,
      0.21505376344086,
      0.0806451612903226,
      0.193548387096774,
      0.510752688172043,
      0.283018867924528,
      0.0566037735849057,
      0.182389937106918,
      0.477987421383648,
      0.224489795918367,
      0.0612244897959184,
      0.17687074829932,
      0.537414965986395,
      0.286585365853659,
      0.0609756097560976,
      0.207317073170732,
      0.445121951219512,
      0.317567567567568,
      0.0878378378378378,
      0.195945945945946,
      0.398648648648649,
      0.273381294964029,
      0.0287769784172662,
      0.215827338129496,
      0.482014388489209,
      0.266187050359712,
      0.0431654676258993,
      0.23021582733813,
      0.460431654676259,
      0.248322147651007,
      0.0671140939597315,
      0.167785234899329,
      0.516778523489933,
      0.210191082802548,
      0.133757961783439,
      0.0828025477707006,
      0.573248407643312,
      0.287958115183246,
      0.0418848167539267,
      0.151832460732984,
      0.518324607329843,
      0.201183431952663,
      0.0532544378698225,
      0.21301775147929,
      0.532544378698225,
      0.269230769230769,
      0.0164835164835165,
      0.142857142857143,
      0.571428571428571,
      0.236111111111111,
      0.0694444444444444,
      0.180555555555556,
      0.513888888888889,
      0.147540983606557,
      0.0491803278688525,
      0.185792349726776,
      0.617486338797814,
      0.227848101265823,
      0.0379746835443038,
      0.126582278481013,
      0.607594936708861,
      0.165644171779141,
      0.049079754601227,
      0.116564417177914,
      0.668711656441718,
      0.157142857142857,
      0.080952380952381,
      0.133333333333333,
      0.628571428571429,
      0.176470588235294,
      0.0633484162895928,
      0.126696832579186,
      0.633484162895928,
      0.133587786259542,
      0.0877862595419847,
      0.099236641221374,
      0.679389312977099,
      0.14344262295082,
      0.040983606557377,
      0.0778688524590164,
      0.737704918032787,
      0.223107569721116,
      0.0836653386454183,
      0.0637450199203187,
      0.629482071713147
    )
  ),
  class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
  row.names = c(NA, -144L),
  groups = structure(
    list(
      year_month = c(
        "2017-01",
        "2017-02",
        "2017-03",
        "2017-04",
        "2017-05",
        "2017-06",
        "2017-07",
        "2017-08",
        "2017-09",
        "2017-10",
        "2017-11",
        "2017-12",
        "2018-01",
        "2018-02",
        "2018-03",
        "2018-04",
        "2018-05",
        "2018-06",
        "2018-07",
        "2018-08",
        "2018-09",
        "2018-10",
        "2018-11",
        "2018-12",
        "2019-01",
        "2019-02",
        "2019-03",
        "2019-04",
        "2019-05",
        "2019-06",
        "2019-07",
        "2019-08",
        "2019-09",
        "2019-10",
        "2019-11",
        "2019-12"
      ),
      .rows = structure(
        list(
          1:4,
          5:8,
          9:12,
          13:16,
          17:20,
          21:24,
          25:28,
          29:32,
          33:36,
          37:40,
          41:44,
          45:48,
          49:52,
          53:56,
          57:60,
          61:64,
          65:68,
          69:72,
          73:76,
          77:80,
          81:84,
          85:88,
          89:92,
          93:96,
          97:100,
          101:104,
          105:108,
          109:112,
          113:116,
          117:120,
          121:124,
          125:128,
          129:132,
          133:136,
          137:140,
          141:144
        ),
        ptype = integer(0),
        class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list")
      )
    ),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
    row.names = c(NA, -36L),
    .drop = TRUE
  )
)


ggplot(data_df)  +  
  geom_bar(aes(x=year_month, 
               y=broj),stat="identity")+ 
  geom_line(aes(x=year_month, 
                y=100*percent,
                colour = obdukcija,
                group = obdukcija),stat="identity",size=2)+ 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis=sec_axis(~.*0.01,
                                       name="Percentage",
                                       labels=scales::percent)
                     )+
  theme_classic()+
   theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))

I hope I made a reproducivle example. Thank you for your help. Can you please expleine me how to properly write code for y axis.

I think that I solve the probplem manually:
 scale_y_continuous(sec.axis=sec_axis(~.*0.005,                                        name="Percentage",                                        labels=scales::percent)                      )

Your guess was not a good one. You need to find the scaling factor when plotting a secondary axis. Since your data frame is grouped on year_month, you can get the maximum value for broj with the following:
library(dplyr)

summarise(data_df, max=sum(broj)) |>
  summarise(max=max(max))
# 262

However, your lines are also grouped by obdukcija, so you need to take this into account.
ungroup(data_df) |>
  summarise(max_pct=sum(percent), .by=c(year_month, obdukcija)) |>
  summarise(max=max(max_pct))
# 0.738

262/0.738
# 355

This means your primary y-axis (left) will be 355 times larger than the secondary y-axis (right). This will be your scaling factor to maximise the visibility of both series within the plotting area.
ggplot(data_df)  +  
  geom_bar(aes(x=year_month, y=broj), stat="identity") + 
  geom_line(aes(x=year_month, 
                y=percent*355,   # Here
                colour = obdukcija,
                group = obdukcija), stat="identity",size=2) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis=sec_axis(~./355,  # And here
                     name="Percentage",                                
                     labels=scales::percent)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))



Great! Thank you @edward. Besides, you provide me a code, you explaine me how to scale it. Thank helps me to adapt all other plots.

do I need to use upper CI as reference point when I have 95CI around line? @edward

Probably. Do you need help with that?
